# MY fragments would not show

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment

Please help!
 I have three fragments that need to be shown on the gallery page, but my app keeps crashing.
This is the gallery.java page

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
 import android.os.Bundle;


public class Gallery extends Activity {
Fragment fragmenta;
Fragment fragmentb;
Fragment fragmentc;
FragmentManager fm;
String fraga;
String fragb;
String fragc;
FragmentTransaction ft;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
    fm = getFragmentManager();
    fragmenta=new FragmentA();
    fragmentb=new FragmentB();
    fragmentc=new FragmentC();
    fragmenta=(Fragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragmenta);
    fragmentb=(Fragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragmentb);
    fragmentc=(Fragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragmentc);

  //  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment,fragmenta,fraga).commit();
  //  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment2,fragmentb,fragb).commit();
  //  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment3,fragmentc,fragc).commit();

    ft=fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.fragment, new FragmentA());
    ft.add(R.id.fragment2, new FragmentB());
    ft.add(R.id.fragment3, new FragmentC());
    ft.commit();





}
```

}

this is frag a. java

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta,container,false);
    return v;
}
```

This is frag b.java

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentb,container,false);
    return v;
}
```

this is frag c.java

```
public class FragmentC extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentc,container,false);
    return v;
}
```

please help

there are three fragments and i need three of them to show on the gallery page. the xml code is ok, so i didn't think to add it here

my gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:name="android.app.DialogFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:name="android.app.DialogFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:name="android.app.DialogFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

Comment: Can you please post the `logcat` showing the crash?

Comment: my logical did not show any errors, idk why

Comment: Okay, I think maybe since you have your three fragments created here `fragmenta=new FragmentA();` then you don't need to `new` them again when adding here `ft.add(R.id.fragment, new FragmentA());`. Try changing those lines to be `ft.add(R.id.fragment, fragmenta);`, and do the same for fragments b and c.

Comment: still did not work. please help me

Comment: Post your Activity Layout xml file if possible.

Comment: You seem to be adding all Fragments twice or what does this code do getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment3,fragmentc,fragc).commit();

Comment: Okay, keep that change though and comment out these lines: `fragmenta=(Fragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragmenta);` because I don't think they are needed. You are re-assigning your fragments but you shouldn't need to do that. You already have the fragment from the layout from `fragmenta=new FragmentA();`.

Comment: still did not work! and my logical isn't helping :( please i need you to help me

Comment: Post your layout XML file since no error is showing strangely

Comment: just added my layout for the gallery.xml holding all three frag

Comment: which ones exactly? and on which of the files?

Comment: You have a static fragments in Layout which means they can't be removed or added so no need to add them in your actvity

Comment: so what exactly do i do so it works?

Comment: Comment out everything after thissetContentView(R.layout.gallery); and let see if there is any error thrown

Comment: OK all your fragments seem to have same name android:name="android.app.DialogFragment" that's not right

Comment: what do i change them to?

Comment: See my answer below and don't forget to qualify the Fragment Names with your domain Name e.g.com.example.yourApp.FragmentA

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:name="com.example.yourApp.FragmentA"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

<fragment
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:name="com.example.yourApp.FragmentB"
android:id="@+id/fragment2"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<fragment
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:name="com.example.yourApp.FragmentC"
android:id="@+id/fragment3"
android:layout_below="@+id/fragment2"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

Comment: it didn't work, do i make any changes to the gallery.java after using this?

Comment: What error does it give and is the layout you posted the gallery Layout?

Comment: In what Layout are these Fragments.  Could you pls post your complete gallery Layout?